# Issues when trying to add new list items using the reference Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to add new items into a Sharepoint List, using a winforms C# app, but I'm getting an error as if the app didn't find the list fields.

My code:

```
using SPC = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

(...)

```
string siteUrl = "https://sharepoint.company.com/sites/ProjectX";

SPC.ClientContext clientContext = new SPC.ClientContext(siteUrl);

string userName = "someone.surname";
SecureString password = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "MyPaSsWoRd".ToCharArray()) password.AppendChar(c);
clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, "MyDomain");

SPC.Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

SPC.List oList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Y");
clientContext.Load(oList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

SPC.ListItemCreationInformation listCreationInformation = new SPC.ListItemCreationInformation();

SPC.ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(listCreationInformation);

oListItem["field 1"] = "a";
oListItem["field 2"] = "b";
oListItem["user"] = "someone.surname";
oListItem["date 1"] = "01/01/2015";
oListItem["field 3"] = "99";

oListItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Error ocurring in the last code line:

> Column 'field 1' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another
>   user.  /sites/ProjectX/Lists/List_Y

Any tip?

PS.: Yes, there is a field named "field 1" on the "List Y".

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should [write out the field names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892430/sharepoint-client-object-model-how-to-get-all-the-fields-in-a-list) for your list, to ensure "field 1" is present in the oList object.

Comment: Thanks @wooters but I've done that already, using the line codes below and all field names are ok:
`SPC.FieldCollection FLDlist = oList.Fields;
clientContext.Load(FLDlist);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
string mmmsg = string.Empty;
foreach (SPC.Field fld in FLDlist)
{
    mmmsg += fld.Title + Environment.NewLine;
}
MessageBox.Show(mmmsg);`

Comment: Have a look at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790926/client-object-model-get-item-by-id-item-does-not-exist-it-may-have-been-delete), if you haven't already.

Comment: Sorry @wooters but I dont understand this: "sharepoint ask you about 'trust' then u have to choose the list wich u want to operate with". I cant see any tipe of "asking" or message from sharepoint.

Comment: Yeah to be honest, I don't fully understand it either. It just looked directly related to the error that you are dealing with.

Comment: no problem @wooters, I thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue cause: I was using the "Display Name" of the fields, but I need to use the "Internal Name" instead.

So I checked in the List settings the Internal Name of the fields and then I used at this part of the code:

```
oListItem["field 1"] = "a";
oListItem["field 2"] = "b";
oListItem["user"] = "someone.surname";
oListItem["date 1"] = "01/01/2015";
oListItem["field 3"] = "99";
```

For example, the Internal Name of the field "field 1" is "f1"; the Internal Name of the "field 2" is "f2"; the Internal Name of the field "date 1" is "date_1"; and so on...

So, when I changed the Display Name into Internal Name (at the "oListItem["..."]), the error message "Column 'field 1' does not exist" doesn't ocurred anymore, because the fields are now found.

Other change I had to do was at this point:

```
oListItem["user"] = "someone.surname";
```

This way doesn't works (set the username directly). I had to use a variable to get the current user. This way:

```
oListItem["user"] = oUser.Id.ToString();
```

Where the "oUser" variable is:

```
SPC.User oUser = oWeb.CurrentUser;
clientContext.Load(oUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

That's it! It's all right now :) Thanks everybody!